# Verify the equation $BO/MN= (NH/LH)(KL/MN)$ in relation to curvature?

Tags: calculus, curvature

[image]

Verify that $BO/MN= (NH/LH)(KL/MN)$, and state why
$$ \frac{BG}{GM}= \frac{HN}{HL} \frac{KL}{MN}$$

I am unsure how to even start this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but look up for the Ceva Theorem

Comment: Is there more information that is not included in the picture?

Comment: No.  That was all I was given to work with.

Comment: Where did the question come from? It is indeed a tough question, so any info on the context is helpful.

Comment: It is a historical method for determining an evolute (locus of centers of curvature) as described [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3007/3730)

Comment: See Fig. 6 of this [document](https://digitalcommons.ursinus.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1004&context=triumphs_calculus) and its comments.